# Condense Makefile.am

Tags: makefile, autotools

I am using autotools to build a project. I have a `configure.ac`, `makefile.am` and `autogen.sh`. This all works great. My Jenkins pipeline can pick this up and run it. My issue is the `makefile.am` is getting longer and longer. Recently I added some 3rd part vendor code to my project.

This is the current `makefile.am`

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign subdir-objects

bin_PROGRAMS = MAIN_Application

MAIN_Application_LDADD = -lsocketcan -lpthread -lm

AM_CPPFLAGS = \
-I$(srcdir)/include \
-I$(srcdir)/include/utilities \
-I$(srcdir)/include/comms \
-I$(srcdir)/include/config_parsing \
-I$(srcdir)/vendor/my_vendor/host/include \
-I$(srcdir)/vendor/my_vendor/host/source/lib/comm_mgr/inc \
-I$(srcdir)/vendor/my_vendor/host/source/lib/mem_pool/inc \
-I$(srcdir)/vendor/my_vendor/host/source/lib/osal/inc \
-I$(srcdir)/vendor/my_vendor/production/source/lib/FFT \
-I$(srcdir)/vendor/my_vendor/public/common \
-I$(srcdir)/vendor/my_vendor/public/host \
-I$(srcdir)/vendor/my_vendor/public/production

MAIN_Application_SOURCES = \
src/main.cpp \
src/scheduler.c \
src/thread_health.c \
src/signal_handler.c \
src/utilities/time_conversions.c \
src/utilities/ring_buffer.c \
src/utilities/logger.c \
src/utilities/string_operations.c \
src/config_parsing/file_operations.c \
src/config_parsing/config_parser.c \
src/comms/can.c \
src/comms/can_ring_buffer.c \
vendor/my_vendor/production/source/lib/FFT/FFT.c \
vendor/my_vendor/production/source/PROD_lib.c \
vendor/my_vendor/host/source/HLB_helper.c \
vendor/my_vendor/host/source/HLB_nscm.c \
vendor/my_vendor/host/source/HLB_apcm.c \
vendor/my_vendor/host/source/HLB_fwload.c \
vendor/my_vendor/host/source/HLB_host.c \
vendor/my_vendor/host/source/HLB_noise_floor.c \
vendor/my_vendor/host/source/lib/mem_pool/src/mem_pool.c \
vendor/my_vendor/host/source/lib/comm_mgr/src/comm_mgr_lib.c \
vendor/my_vendor/host/source/lib/osal/src/osal.c \
vendor/my_vendor/host/source/HLB_legacy_commands.c \
vendor/my_vendor/host/source/HLB_protocol.c
```

Do I really have to include each `.c` file individually? Why does `vendor/my_vendor/host/*/**` not work? How can I compress this `makefile.am`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autotools developers consider it to be best practice to explicitly list all the source files.  This avoids things like test or debug sources etc. creeping into distribution packages.

You can't use `**` because this syntax is a non-standard extension available specifically in shells like `bash` and `zsh`, that is not supported by standard POSIX globbing (which is what make uses for its glob expansion).

I think it would work to use simple globbing (that is, `*.c`) in `Makefile.am` but of course you'd still need to use each directory.

Just to add:

You can also make your makefile "tidier" by breaking up the sources into sections.  So for example you might have something like:

```
MAIN_Application_SOURCES = \
    src/main.cpp \
    src/scheduler.c \
    src/thread_health.c \
    src/signal_handler.c

MAIN_Application_SOURCES += \
    src/utilities/time_conversions.c \
    src/utilities/ring_buffer.c \
    src/utilities/logger.c \
    src/utilities/string_operations.c

MAIN_Application_SOURCES += \
    src/config_parsing/file_operations.c \
    src/config_parsing/config_parser.c

MAIN_Application_SOURCES += \
    src/comms/can.c \
    src/comms/can_ring_buffer.c

MAIN_Application_SOURCES += \
    vendor/my_vendor/production/source/lib/FFT/FFT.c \
    vendor/my_vendor/production/source/PROD_lib.c \
    vendor/my_vendor/host/source/HLB_helper.c \
    vendor/my_vendor/host/source/HLB_nscm.c \
    vendor/my_vendor/host/source/HLB_apcm.c \
    vendor/my_vendor/host/source/HLB_fwload.c \
    vendor/my_vendor/host/source/HLB_host.c \
    vendor/my_vendor/host/source/HLB_noise_floor.c \
    vendor/my_vendor/host/source/lib/mem_pool/src/mem_pool.c \
    vendor/my_vendor/host/source/lib/comm_mgr/src/comm_mgr_lib.c \
    vendor/my_vendor/host/source/lib/osal/src/osal.c \
    vendor/my_vendor/host/source/HLB_legacy_commands.c \
    vendor/my_vendor/host/source/HLB_protocol.c
```

or something like that, or you could even use other variables and then add them together.  Maybe that helps with readability.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to believe you. I did a search of GitHub for makefile.am. Even large developers like VLC have to list each and every source file.

Comment: I'm not seeing what you think the problem is with that, @Michael, and I must say that from my perspective, the `Makefile.am` you present is pretty short and sweet.  Maybe a little excessive on the `CPPFLAGS`, but that's not what you're asking about, and probably not something that you could easily fix.

Comment: The reality is that you only add new files to your system pretty rarely and it's not such a big ask to update the list of files on those rare occasions ... and it really is better to have an explicit list than to be dumping random test files you forgot about into your built packages (remember the main goal of autotools is to create portable source packages that can be compiled on lots of different systems).

Comment: The two of you are correct. My current makefile is short and you do only edit it as new files are added. My issue with it is I am adding third party vendor code. They have many files and I had to enter each one manually. I was only hoping for a shortcut.

Comment: Why manually enter those files? That is what shells are for: `find vendor/my_vendor -type f -name '*.c' | sed 's|^|MAIN_Application_SOURCES += |' > my_vendor.mki` and then just add `include my_vendor.mki` to your `Makefile.am` file. Or append that to `Makefile.am`. Or...